# Install: no hard drive detected?

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.04.3 on my old HP desktop. Setup runs fine until I get to the installation type (partition) window. The installer is not detecting the Seagate SATA hard drive, and only shows the /dev/sda (the usb installer) as a device for boot loader installation. I checked multiple other questions and tried to replicate what they did, nothing has worked so far.

What I've done:
Played with BIOS settings to change the SATA controller to IDE and AHCI, both didn't work. 
Plugged the HDD into every SATA port on the motherboard.
I've been able to install Ubuntu on different PCs before without any issues, this is the first time I've not been able to locate the HDD in the installer.

This is a 64 bit system on AMD Phenom II x4. Windows 10 is installed on the HDD.

Comment: Is there any space available on the drive? Depending on what you are trying to do (dual boot, etc) you could try to work around this by booting to the live USB and setting up your partitions using gparted, then running the installer.

Comment: Show me a current-window-only screenshot of `gparted` view of /dev/sda, and I'll take a look. Was/is your BIOS set to RAID first? What is it set to now? Do you have a hardware RAID card?

Comment: BIOS was set for AHCI first. I did try RAID but it didn't work. I found an old Western Digital hard drive laying around and Ubuntu detected that no problem (still does not detect the Seagate). This might be an issue with brands then? The Seagate drive is 1TB in size and hardly has anything on it (just win10 install).

Comment: http://storage2.static.itmages.com/i/17/0807/h_1502137597_3096092_d13467d956.png

Comment: I tried formatting the seagate drive and received an error in Ubuntu. Not sure how to access it now.

Comment: I was able to format the hard drive, and now is usable by the system. I still do not know why the installer could not detect the hard drive.

Answer (score -1):

You need to delete Windows boot partition (EFS) to install Ubuntu, I faced the same issue during installation in Acer predator 500. If deleting only EFS (use gparted preinstalled in ubuntu Live boot partions are marked as esp under flags) does not work then you need to delete windows partition + Microsoft reserved partition + EFS this would definitely works.
It is recommended to backup anything useful in Windows Partition.
If deleting EFS works then search for a way to recover EFS  in windows 10 < https://www.disk-partition.com/windows-10/accidentally-deleted-boot-partition-windows-10.html > Try: Method in which Windows bootable drive is used. I used this and it worked for me.

And If you're using an Optane Drive then expect delay in booting to Ubuntu almost everytime.